# How can I check the version of Excel files in C#?

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I need to differentiate that a selected file is created with Excel 2010 or Excel 2013 version of a selected Excel file and Excel application on server must match in order to continue.

I can get the server's Excel application version:

```
 xApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
// getting version of Server's Excel Application
string versionName = xApp.Version;
int length = versionName.IndexOf('.');
versionName = versionName.Substring(0, length);
object missing = Type.Missing;
object trueObject = true;
xApp.Visible = false;
xApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
xWorkBook = 
xApp.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFilePath, missing, trueObject, 
                    missing, missing, missing,
                    missing, missing, missing,
                    missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);
```

But how can I get the Excel version of opened Excel files?
In the current case, `versionName` returns `14.0`, which is for Office 2010.

Comment: Office Interop have [many issues](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757/en-us), consider using [OpenXML](http://openxmldeveloper.org/) which appears to have [what you seek for](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.fileversion(v=office.15).aspx) or its wrapper [ClosedXML](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found a simple solution with **OLE File Property Reader**

```
var doc = new OleDocumentPropertiesClass();
doc.Open(ExcelFilePath, false, dsoFileOpenOptions.dsoOptionDefault);
string DocFileVersion = doc.SummaryProperties.Version.ToString();
```

this will return version of Application Version of excel file...

Answer (score 1):

For `.xls` files you need to decode the "BIFF" value, from [MSDN: How To Determine the Version of a Microsoft Excel Workbook](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/178605):

> Microsoft Excel saves data using structured storage. In particular, it creates a data stream called "Workbook" (previously just "Book") where it saves the contents starting with a BOF (beginning of file) record.

There's also some code in that article but I'm unsure how much I can lift from it without breaching copyright.

That format is used up to Excel 2002 according to a table at the bottom of that article.

As for `.xlsx` files, you can use any zip file library to open it, then open the `docProps\app.xml` file, and inside you'll find this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Properties xmlns=...>
    ....
    <AppVersion>15.0300</AppVersion>
</Properties>
```

This will tell you the version of Excel that saved that particular file.

Also note that Excel will determine whether to use new storage loading or old storage loading depending on the *contents* of the file and not only on the extension, as such you can store an old-style file with a .xlsx extension and a new-style file with a .xls extension and Excel will still open it, and so should you. Excel will give a warning though, how you handle the discrepancy is up to you.

Comment: can you please show me a way how to use zip library to open excel file ?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in code, you can have switch case to detect what version of file it is.

```
Excel 95 (v7.0)
Excel 97 (v8.0)
Excel 2000 (v9.0)
Excel 2002 (v10.0)
Excel 2003 (v11.0)
Excel 2007 (v12.0)
Excel 2010 (v14.0)
Excel 2013 (v15.0)
```

Comment: this code gives me version of excel application on Server... I want to get the Application version of Excel File selected by user. Simple idea is that if excel Application of Server and Uploaded file matches then user can go forward otherwise not...