# How To Determine Which Version of Excel last saved a Workbook

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I have some excel files (.xls) that is being automatically generated from some system, and I am distributing these files to some users and they edit some fields in it and send it back to me.
I need to know from each file they sent me which version of excel they are using (is it office 2003, 2007, 2010, 2013...?) because I want to know what is the lowest versions I need to keed support for.

Is there a way to take these files and get the excel version that saved each one of them ?

I tried this solution [Programmatically finding an Excel file's Excel version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070985/programmatically-finding-an-excel-files-excel-version) but it didn't do it...

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27834386/how-can-i-check-the-version-of-excel-files-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for, at least it worked fine for my application.

```
 var excelWB = new OleDocumentPropertiesClass();
 excelWB.Open(FilePath, false, dsoFileOpenOptions.dsoOptionDefault);
 string FileUsedVersion = excelWB.SummaryProperties.Version.ToString();
```

Greetings

Comment: I used it (as I menthioned in the link) but this doe not support .xlsx files...

Comment: The link mentioned using the DocumentType property it did not mention using the SummaryProperties.Version. If you alrdy used this version too the answer is obsolete.

Comment: Oh... :-) Sorry, Didn't see it :-)

Comment: I'm getting this error on your code: `Interop type 'DSOFile.OleDocumentPropertiesClass' cannot be embedded. Use the applicable interface instead.`

Comment: Right click the DLL in the References tab than set Embbed Interop Types to false.